# Copy vector to vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a simple question about how can I copy a vector into another. I have a vector with a length of 66x1 and then, another with a length of 2151x1. I want to copy the values from the first one in a exactly position on the other. I've tried that but it doesn't work.

inter= 66x1
out= 2151x1

```
for i=1:numel(inter)
    out(101:167)= inter(i)
end
```

Also I've tried this:

```
for inter=(1:66);
    out(101:167)=inter;
end
```

And this:

```
for k= (101:167)
    out(k)=inter(1:66);
end
```

Am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your problem is a misunderstanding of the for loop. The variable in the for line is just a number (= 1x1 matrix) - while in the loop you assign it to a vector (66x1 matrix) repeatedly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say your vectors are

```
a = [1; 2; 3];
b = [4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9];
```

for simplicity.

There is no need to use loops. You can just go ahead and do it like this:

```
startIdx = 2; %101 in your case
finalIdx = startIdx + size(a,1) - 1; % 166 in your case
b(startIdx:finalIdx) = a;
```

Then b would be:

```
b =

     4
     1
     2
     3
     8
     9
```

---

A very important point here is the `-1` in `finalIdx`. You need to substract 1 from the final index.

Comment: Or just do `out(101:166) = inter` :-)